# How do I specify a struct as the return value of a function in RubyFFI?

Tags: ruby, function, struct, return-type, ffi

I have to load several functions that return structures from the library itself.

```
attach_function 'fn_name', [], # ... What do I put here?
```

RubyFFI's Wiki pages seem to be outdated, so I'm a little lost here.

How do I create a `FFI::Struct`, and how do I specify it as the return type of a native function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class SOME_STRUCT < FFI::Struct 
    layout :a, :float, 
           :b, :float
end
```

and then

```
attach_function 'fn_name', [], SOME_STRUCT
```

and if it stack-allocated struct:

```
typedef struct
{ 
    float a, b; 
} SOME_STRUCT;
```

you should use this:

```
attach_function 'fn_name', [], SOME_STRUCT.by_value
```

Comment: As of ffi-1.0 (and JRuby 1.6.0), use SOME_STRUCT.by_ref as the return type if the function returns a reference to a struct - when you just use SOME_STRUCT, you get back a FFI::Pointer instead of an instance of SOME_STRUCT.  You can also use the shorthand SOME_STRUCT.ptr, and SOME_STRUCT.val - whichever floats your boat.