# How to wrap function in Ruby FFI method that takes struct as argument?

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am trying to call a function from a shared object using ruby-ffi. I compiled the following into a shared object:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _WHAT {
  int d;
  void * something;
} WHAT;

int doit(WHAT w) {
  printf("%d\n", w.d);
  return w.d;
}
```

The problem is, how do I declare the function with `attach_function` in Ruby? How is the struct argument (WHAT w) defined in the list of arguments in Ruby? It is not a :pointer, and does not seem to fit any of the other available types described in the ruby-ffi documentation, so what would it be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check **how to use Structs** in https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Structs, for your case:

```
class What < FFI::Struct
  layout :d, :int,
         :something, :pointer
end
```

Now **attach the function**, the argument, since you are **passing the struct by value**, is going to be `What.by_value`(replacing What by whatever you have named you struct class above):

```
attach_function 'doit', [What.by_value],:int
```

And now **how to call the function**:

```
mywhat = DoitLib::What.new
mywhat[:d] = 1234
DoitLib.doit(mywhat)
```

And now the complete file:

```
require 'ffi'

module DoitLib
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib "path/to/yourlibrary.so"

  class What < FFI::Struct
    layout :d, :int,
           :something, :pointer
  end

  attach_function 'doit', [What.by_value],:int

end

mywhat = DoitLib::What.new
mywhat[:d] = 1234
DoitLib.doit(mywhat)
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I was under the impression that if the argument is not defined as a pointer in the C library, some other special handling is required.

Comment: Sorry, Jorge, but when I run this code, it gives back a long number that looks more like an address than the integer I pass in. Are you sure about this?

Comment: I missed to put the calling convention on the example, can you try putting `ffi_convention :stdcall` just after `ffi_lib ...`. If not try `ffi_convention :default`(although I think that one is the default and you shouldn't need to specify it). Let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment, I wiped up a quick library and a test  and got the same behavior that you describe (big number instead of the expected int). Let me get back to you if I find what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I have tried both, but I still get the same result. I also tried replacing the :pointer in the argument list with the name of the FFI::Struct class (like What in your example), as shown in the following SO question, but nothing works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372483/how-do-i-specify-a-struct-as-the-return-value-of-a-function-in-rubyffi

Comment: Ok, found a workaround. Change this in your code. `int doit(WHAT *w) {
  printf("%d\n", w->d);
  return w->d;
}`. Instead of passing it by value you pass it by reference, with a pointer. That will get it working, I will check if you can manage to get it working with your original code.

Comment: Ok, got it :D . Everything is the same except the attach_function. try with this (keeping you C code as it initially was) `attach_function 'doit', [What.by_value],:int`. That should work, let me know and I would fix my answer accordingly for the future.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Where did you find this info? This should be in the wiki. Will you put it there or shall I?

Comment: This may be helpful for using some of the msvcrt.dll calls that ffi has in FFI::Library::LIBC  see:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2(v=vs.80).aspx  It is also in most microsoft help viewers under C runtime libraries